# Python : Use a list as dictionary key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, hash

I'm sure the solution to my issue is pretty simple but I couldn't find it out.

When running this, I'm getting

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

which is expected since I'm working with a list:

```
import operator
import shutil

def start(source):
    source=open('Book.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
    wordslist=[]
    for word in source:
        content=word.lower().split()
        for each_word in content:
            #print(each_word)
            wordslist.append(content)

    #cleanuptext(wordslist)
    sortdictionnary(wordslist)
'''
def cleanuptext(wordslist):
    cleanwords=[]
    for cleanword in wordslist:
        symbols=',.'
        for i in range(0, len(symbols)):
            cleanword = str(cleanword).replace(symbols[i], "")
            if len(cleanword) > 0:
                print(cleanword)
                cleanwords.append(cleanword)
'''
def sortdictionnary(wordslist):
    counter={}
    for word in wordslist:
        if word in counter:
            counter[word] += 1
        else:
            counter[word] = 1
    for key, value in sorted(counter.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
        print(key, value)
start(source='Book.txt')
```

How can I avoid this problem and be able to use my list in my dictionary?

Eventhough I tried to use Counter, I got the same issue :

```
import operator
import shutil
from collections import Counter


def start(source):
    source=open('Book.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
    wordslist=[]
    for word in source:
        content=word.lower().split()
        for each_word in content:
            #print(each_word)
            wordslist.append(content)

    #cleanuptext(wordslist)
    sortdictionnary(wordslist)
'''
def cleanuptext(wordslist):
    cleanwords=[]
    for cleanword in wordslist:
        symbols=',.'
        for i in range(0, len(symbols)):
            cleanword = str(cleanword).replace(symbols[i], "")
            if len(cleanword) > 0:
                print(cleanword)
                cleanwords.append(cleanword)
'''
def sortdictionnary(wordslist):
    coun = Counter()
    for word in wordslist:
        if word in coun:
            coun[word] += 1
        else:
            coun[word] = 1
    for key, value in sorted(coun.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
        print(key, value)
start(source='Book.txt')
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: I tried running your sortdictionary() method, it is running just fine, probably error is somewhere in your start() method or the 'Book.txt'
Can you share start() code along with some sample data from Book.txt?

Comment: Hello Rahul,

I've edited my code. 

Thanks :)

Comment: tuples are hashable and very list-like. Also, you have `collections.Counter` that does what I believe you're trying to do with `sortdictionnary()`.

Comment: Hello @Todd,

I'm beginning on Python. 
Could you please tell me if I need to add a class "class collections.Counter" in which I need to include my code? 

Thanks.

Comment: You need; `from collections import Counter`. then you can create a `Counter`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: `for key, value in sorted(c.items()):` should do the same thing you have on that line.

Comment: I did and I got the same issue. 
I edited my post to include this part of code. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that `list` are mutable and you cannot use a mutable value as key in a dictionary. An alternative is to use a `tuple`

```
content = tuple(word.lower().split())
```

To understand the reason Python doesn't want mutable values as keys consider that you put two different keys `a` and `b` in a dictionary with two values, and then you mutate the mutable `a` (the first key) so that it becomes equal to `b`... what should happen to the dictionary? In a Python dictionary there cannot be two equal keys with distinct values.

Tuples are ok as keys because they're similar to lists but immutable.

Comment: So even when using "Counter (from collections)", I must use something immutable like tuples, right ?

Comment: @XXX: yes... anything that is based on hashing (e.g. also `set`) requires immutable values

Comment: Great, thanks ! 
One more question please : Is this behavior relatively "brand new"? Because I saw on old tutorials that It was allowed. 

Thanks again.

Comment: @XXX: I don't know but this "limitation" is surely quite old... may be since Python 1.x